# Union statement with duplicate response even with group by

Tags: sql

UNION with statement coming back with the duplicate loan_type_response

```
    lt.loan_type_id,
    lt.loan_type_name,
         (SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(la.loan_amount), 0), ', ', COUNT(loan.loan_id))
                FROM loan
                JOIN loan_amount la ON la.loan_amount_id = loan.ref_loan_amount_id
                JOIN loan2event l2e ON l2e.ref_loan_id = loan.loan_id AND l2e.end IS NULL and DATE(l2e.start) = CURDATE() AND l2e.ref_event_id IN (1301)
                WHERE loan.ref_loan_type_id = lt.loan_type_id) as amount_count
FROM loan_type lt
WHERE lt.active = 1
  GROUP BY lt.loan_type_id

UNION

 SELECT
        lt.loan_type_id,
        lt.loan_type_name,           
             (SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(la.loan_amount), 0), ', ', COUNT(loan.loan_id))
                    FROM loan
                    JOIN loan_amount la ON la.loan_amount_id = loan.ref_loan_amount_id
                    JOIN loan2event l2e1 ON l2e1.ref_loan_id = loan.loan_id AND l2e1.end IS NULL AND l2e1.ref_event_id IN ("1004 "," 1101 "," 1105")
                   WHERE loan.ref_loan_type_id = lt.loan_type_id ) as amount_count
FROM loan_type lt
   WHERE lt.active = 1
  GROUP BY lt.`loan_type_name`
```

Response:

```
New 1200, 4
Advanced    750, 5
Basic   NULL
New 6050, 17
Advanced    NULL
Basic   3150, 11
```

Would like to see it grouped by loan_id

```
   New Loan 7250, 21
   Advanced 750, 5
   Basic    3150, 11
```

Comment: The Union would not add up the values for you ...You could put an outer select that adds up the amount_count

Comment: Thank your for your response. Ok, I was under the impression that UNION would sum the results of the 2 sub-queries  I'm just starting with mysql and this is the most complex statement I've done to date.   Could you provide a quick example of how the outer select would be done in this case? If I need to post more information please let me know.

Comment: SQL too big for comments section so posted as answer

Answer (score 0):

Heres the basic syntax of how I would do it in SQL server, I imagine it should work in MySQL as well with some tweaks -

`SELECT loan_type_id, 
loan_type_name, 
SUM(amount_count)
FROM
(SELECT
lt.loan_type_id,
    lt.loan_type_name,
         (SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(la.loan_amount), 0), ', ', COUNT(loan.loan_id))
                FROM loan
                JOIN loan_amount la ON la.loan_amount_id = loan.ref_loan_amount_id
                JOIN loan2event l2e ON l2e.ref_loan_id = loan.loan_id AND l2e.end IS NULL and DATE(l2e.start) = CURDATE() AND l2e.ref_event_id IN (1301)
                WHERE loan.ref_loan_type_id = lt.loan_type_id) as amount_count
FROM loan_type lt
WHERE lt.active = 1
  GROUP BY lt.loan_type_id
UNION
SELECT
        lt.loan_type_id,
        lt.loan_type_name, 
             (SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(la.loan_amount), 0), ', ', COUNT(loan.loan_id))
                    FROM loan
                    JOIN loan_amount la ON la.loan_amount_id = loan.ref_loan_amount_id
                    JOIN loan2event l2e1 ON l2e1.ref_loan_id = loan.loan_id AND l2e1.end IS NULL AND l2e1.ref_event_id IN ("1004 "," 1101 "," 1105")
                   WHERE loan.ref_loan_type_id = lt.loan_type_id ) as amount_count FROM loan_type lt
   WHERE lt.active = 1
  GROUP BY lt.loan_type_name) UnionResult
GROUP BY loan_type_id, loan_type_name`